# How to segment data in pandas more cleanly?

Tags: python, pandas

I have tax data that I imported into pandas, and I want to look at certain segments of the data so that I can analyze that segment of the population. The way I did that was to make new data frames like so

```
new_df = old_tax_df[(old_tax_df.var_1 == 1) & (old_tax_df.var_2 == 1)]
```

Is there a way to do this without making data frames, that would make the code cleaner?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try [`.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html#pandas-dataframe-query) method it is a bit more readable:

```
new_df = old_tax_df.query('var_1 == 1 and var_2 == 1')
```

Or as MaxU points out in the comments.

```
new_df = old_tax_df.query("var_1 == var_2 == 1")
```

Will work also.

Comment: we can do it even nicer: `df.query("var_1 == var_2 == 1")` ;-)

Comment: Looks pretty clean with the use of `query`, nice!

Comment: This answer mixes two languages. The query language and python. This is usually considered bad practice and a smell by clean code standards. The `.query` method can be used for piping GUI input to code, but should not be used in production code.

Answer (score 2):

One approach -

```
old_tax_df[(old_tax_df[['var_1','var_2']]==1).all(1)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [68]: old_tax_df
Out[68]: 
   var_1  var_2  var_3  var_4
0      0      1      0      1
1      1      1      0      2
2      2      1      1      1
3      1      0      1      2
4      1      2      0      2
5      2      0      1      1
6      2      0      0      2
7      0      2      2      0
8      1      1      0      1
9      2      1      1      1

# Original code
In [69]: old_tax_df[(old_tax_df.var_1 == 1) & (old_tax_df.var_2 == 1)]
Out[69]: 
   var_1  var_2  var_3  var_4
1      1      1      0      2
8      1      1      0      1

# Proposed code
In [70]: old_tax_df[(old_tax_df[['var_1','var_2']]==1).all(1)]
Out[70]: 
   var_1  var_2  var_3  var_4
1      1      1      0      2
8      1      1      0      1

# Alternative using `.eq` to replace `==1`
In [76]: old_tax_df[old_tax_df[['var_1','var_2']].eq(1).all(1)]
Out[76]: 
   var_1  var_2  var_3  var_4
1      1      1      0      2
8      1      1      0      1
```

Answer (score 0):

## Using `.groupby`

You could use the groupby method, then access the groups.

```
groups = df.groupby(['var_1', 'var_2', 'var_3', 'var_4'])
groups.get_group((2, 0, 0, 2))
```

This is one way of segmenting one dataframe into multiple dataframes based on values in it.

## Using `.loc`

```
df.set_index(['var_1', 'var_2', 'var_3', 'var_4'], inplace=True)
df.loc[2, 0, 0, 2]
```

Will yield the same result, except that the dataframe will now be indexed on the variable fields.

More about this subject can be found in the [Indexing and Selecting Data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) documentation page for Pandas.